# Filter Value Displaying Strange in Django

Tags: python, django, filter, aggregate-functions

I am using a filter and `.aggregate` to sum up the value of a column `cases` in my `Manifests` model. When this displays in the template it gives me the correct amount, but when the page displays it shows as, for example, `{'cases__sum': 1192}`.  The number `1192` there is indeed the sum, but I don't want the rest of the text to show to the user!  How can I stop this and get just the number?

**views.py**

```
def add_manifest(request, reference_id):
    form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                order = Orders.objects.get(id=reference_id)
                instance.reference = order
            except Orders.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            instance.save()
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id)})
    reference = request.POST.get('reference')
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference)
    total_cases = Manifests.objects.filter(reference=reference).aggregate(Sum('cases')) #totaling the cases for the readonly field
    totalCNF = 0
    for item in manifests:
        totalCNF += item.cases * item.CNF

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'reference_id': reference_id,
        'manifests' : manifests,
        'total_cases': total_cases,
        'totalCNF': totalCNF,

    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

**add_manifest.html**

```
  <label for="form.reference" class="formlabels">Case Total:</label><br>
  <input type="text" value="{{ total_cases }}" readonly>
```

I just want the number, not the whole reference to display in this HTML input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate values are stored in dictionaries. You can use

```
{{ total_cases.cases__sum }}
```

to show the value only, or do it while constructing your context variable:

```
...
'total_cases': total_cases['cases__sum'],
```